# Merging Content from the same field across multiple records through SQL in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have a DE that collects information about past reservations for travel. One of the fields is named FareDiscountCode.

I currently have in place a query from that table that combines all of the reservations for a particular email address to give me a total ride count.

What I would also like to do with that query is combine all of the FareDiscountCodes ever used by that email address. Is that possible in the SFMC environment?

My current query looks like this:

```
select Count(Distinct(b.BookingID)) as "TotalRides", b.EmailAddress
from "REZ-RideHistory" as b

group by b.EmailAddress
```

would that query look like this?:

```
select Count(Distinct(b.BookingID)) as "TotalRides", CONCAT(b.FareDiscountCode, " ") AS RedeemPromCodes, b.EmailAddress
from "REZ-RideHistory" as b

group by b.EmailAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a go assuming your first query works.

```
select Count(Distinct(b.BookingID)) as "TotalRides",
 STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + [FareDiscountCode] 
    FROM [REZ-RideHistory] as A 
    WHERE (b.EmailAddress= A.EmailAddress) 
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
  ,1,2,'') AS RedeemPromCodes,
  b.EmailAddress
from [REZ-RideHistory] as b

group by b.EmailAddress
```

Also make sure the field length for RedeemPromCodes is sufficient